# ssh-agent running differently on two VMs

Tags: linux, ssh-agent

I have two openSUSE 13.1 VMs. Both have been set up to run ssh-agent and ssh-add when KDE loads up. This is done via the `.bash_profile` file using the following code:

```
# Load SSH agent

SSH_DIR="${HOME}/.ssh"
SSH_ENV="${SSH_DIR}/environment"

function start_agent {
     echo "Initialising new SSH agent..."
     /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
     echo succeeded
     chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null

     for key in ${SSH_DIR}/{id_rsa}
     do
          ssh-add ${key}
     done
}

# Source SSH settings, if applicable

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    #ps ${SSH_AGENT_PID} doesn't work under cywgin
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
         start_agent;
     }
else
     start_agent;
fi
```

This works on one of the VMs. I am prompted to enter passphrase for my SSH key when KDE starts (but before it is fully loaded). Running `ps` indicates only a singular instance of `ssh-agent`.

On the other VM, though, it doesn't work. I must have changed something without thinking because it worked at one point. I don't get prompted for my SSH key passphrase at all. However, running `ps` indicates a couple instances of `ssh-agent` running and seemingly from different points of initiation:

```
 1231 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --sh-syntax --close-stderr --exit-with-session /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
 1233 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

I'm guessing that because ssh-agent is already running the instance attempted via the `.bash_profile` file fails. I do know that if I execute `echo ${SSH_ENV}` on the system it works on I get `/home/msnyder/.ssh/environment`. Doing the same on the VM that isn't working returns nothing.

In the past I would run ssh-askpass via the KDE Autostart directory. I opted for a more shell-oriented method, though, hence what I'm doing (and attempting to do) now.

I don't know what is causing this difference. The `.bash_profile` entries are identical. Anyone have an idea?

EDIT: `kdm` appears to be launching `ssh-agent`. I can't figure out why, though.

```
root       751  0.0  0.0  24612   308 ?        Ss   16:42   0:00 /usr/bin/kdm
root       784  1.7 10.7 282468 110040 tty7    Ssl+ 16:42   0:29  \_ /usr/bin/Xorg -br :0 vt7 -nolisten tcp -auth /var/lib/kdm/AuthFiles/A:0-eGk8Rb
root      1086  0.0  0.0  78344   556 ?        S    16:42   0:00  \_ -:0         
msnyder   1110  0.0  0.0  13092   304 ?        Ss   16:42   0:00      \_ /bin/sh /usr/bin/startkde
msnyder   1233  0.0  0.0  12564    76 ?        Ss   16:42   0:00          \_ /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

As far as I'm aware I haven't configured `KDE`/`kdm` to do this.